# batchall.sign throws TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'specVersion')

Tags: parachain, transactions, error, batch

Trying to form a batchAll command that carries out 2 activities:

1. Deposit 1 GLMR from wallet1 to wallet2
2. Cancel tokens' delegation revoke

When I try to sign the batch with wallet1 (**batchAllExtrinsic.sign**) I get:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'specVersion')`

My async main function looks as follows:

```
const wsProvider = new WsProvider("wss://wss.api.moonbeam.network");
const api = await ApiPromise.create({ 
      provider: wsProvider,
      types: {
        // Add any custom types here
        AccountId: "EthereumAccountId",
        Address: "AccountId",
        Balance: "u128",
        RefCount: "u8",
        LookupSource: "AccountId"
      } 
    });

// Wait for the api to be ready
await api.isReady;

const keyringECDSA = new Keyring({ type: "ethereum" });
const feesWallet = keyringECDSA.addFromUri(PRIVATE_KEY_FEE_WALLET);
const stakedWallet = keyringECDSA.addFromUri(PRIVATE_KEY_STAKED_WALLET);

const amount = 1_000_000_000_000_000;

// Create the batchAll extrinsic with the staking actions
const batchAllExtrinsic = api.tx.utility.batchAll([
   api.tx.balances.transfer(feesWalletH160, amount),
   api.tx.parachainStaking.cancelDelegationRequest(addressCollator3)
]);

// Get the latest block hash
const latestBlockHash = await api.rpc.chain.getFinalizedHead();
    
// Get the block hash and nonce for signing
const blockHash = await api.rpc.chain.getBlock(latestBlockHash);
const { nonce } = await api.query.system.account(feesWallet.address);
const genesisHash = api.genesisHash;
const specVersion = api.runtimeVersion.specVersion;
const transactionVersion = api.runtimeVersion.transactionVersion;

// Sign the batch call using both wallets
batchAllExtrinsic.sign(feesWallet, { blockHash, nonce, genesisHash, specVersion,transactionVersion});
batchAllExtrinsic.addSignature(stakedWallet.address, stakedWallet.sign(batchAllExtrinsic));

// Send the batch call
    batchAllExtrinsic.send(({ status }) => {
        if (status.isInBlock) {
            console.log(`Transaction included in block ${status.asInBlock}`);
        } else if (status.isFinalized) {
            console.log(`Transaction finalized in block ${status.asFinalized}`);
        process.exit(0);
        }    
    });
```

Tried various workarounds (setting api setRuntimeVersion, changing batchAll to batch, replacing the txs with different methods) but nothing seems to solve this error.
Your help will be strongly appreciated